# Disable auto-adjust width of panes in double-pane mode in Caja

Tags: 20.04, caja

I've recently fresh installed `Ubuntu MATE 20.04` (previously used `Ubuntu MATE 16.04`) and noticed the annoying feature of `Caja` file manager (version `1.24.0`). This feature appears in double-pane mode (with "Extra pane", after `F3` pressed) when the "Location bar" is enabled.

While both panes show the same directory, **the width of panes are equals** (see screenshot1).
[image]

Once you move into any folder **the width of the active pane increases** (see screenshot2) adjusting to the "Location bar" width.
[image]

Firstly, this is annoying, because the width "jumps" each time and it distracts very much. Secondary, if the path on the one pane becomes long enough (see screenshot3), **the other pane becomes very narrow** that is very uncomfortable.
[image]

I've checked that in `Ubuntu MATE 16.04` the width of the panes in `Caja` (version `1.12.7`) keeps constant when moving between folders.

**Is it possible to configure `Caja` to keep the width of the panes?
Or should it be downgraded only?**

**UPD:**
A part-solution was proposed by Ubuntu MATE community, see [this post](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-disable-auto-adjust-width-of-panes-in-double-pane-mode-in-caja/22528). When the *text-based* location bar is enabled, there is no auto-adjust behavior. However, the *button* location bar is more convenient, so the question remains open.